# Lambda operations in K-theory

Tags: reference-request, k-theory, algebraic-k-theory, lambda-rings

In Weibel's K-Book, before defining the lambda-operations on higher (Quillen) K-theory, he states that "Although many constructions of $\lambda$-operations have been proposed in more exotic settings, we shall restrict our attention in this section to operations defined using the $+$-construction."

I would actually very much like to hear about those more exotic settings. Could you point me to references which describe various general constructions of $\lambda$-operations in (various flavour of) K-theory? The more general the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~dan/cv.xhtml#extpow](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Edan/cv.xhtml#extpow) for a paper of mine and a link to one of Thomas Gunnarsson and Roland Schwänzl.